# PHP ImageMagick setColorspace not working

Tags: php, imagemagick

I'm trying to convert an image to black and white by altering the colorspace with this code:

```
$im = new Imagick('image.png');
$im->setImageColorspace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_GRAY);
$im->writeImage('out.png');
```

However after this code, there is no visible change to the image (out.png and image.png look indistinguishable). Any thoughts on why this might be? Is this the proper method to convert and image to B&W? Are there any other methods?

I've also tried setColorspace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_GRAY); with the same results.

Here's the software I'm using:

```
ImageMagick 6.6.9-7
PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.1
Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
```

Edit: Some extra info

I've also tried converting to other colorspaces (specifically CMY and CMYK) and noticed no visual difference then either.

Comment: I have the same issue as well. any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative, you can try `$im->modulateImage(100,0,100);` instead of `setImageColorspace()`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ha! I swear I tried this and it didn't work. On a whim, I just tried it again and it was very successful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The correct function to use is Imagick::transformImageColorspace . Hmmm, apparently it is not currently documented.

Here it is in action being used to transform an image and then analyze a single channel of that image http://www.phpimagick.com/Imagick/transformImageColorspace