# How to stop browser making images fainter

Tags: php, google-chrome, firefox, png, imagick

I've noticed the following behaviour in Chrome and Firefox on Ubuntu Linux and Windows 8:

A greyscale image containing text is perfectly legible when viewed in a picture editor, but browsers somehow make the greys much paler than the image is when viewed in them (Chrome, Firefox) [image: Screenshot of the same image opened in 1) Ubuntu Image viewer and 2) Firefox and displayed side by side]

Does anybody have an idea if there is a way to stop this or control it, perhaps via Javascript, server headers, etc? Is there some sort of encoding in the images themselves which is not clearly setting the correct gray tone to use?

Not sure when this started happening, but this image is from a website that has perhaps a million such images, and there never used to be a problem.

Comment: This problem appears not to affect Internet Explorer.

Comment: could this be the issue? https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/865066

Comment: Thanks, but no that's not it.

Comment: Is the image being displayed in the browser at its intrinsic size, or are you scaling the image in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason turns out to be connected with missing metadata stored in the png files which meant the images were not being assigned a correct default ICC colour profile. Older browsers didn't bother with colour profiles, which in this case meant they actually displayed the images "properly" in the past, but new browsers displayed faint images.

With pngs it is possible to set a single byte property in the image metadata which instructs image renderers to use the sRGB ICC image colour profile.

---

**UPDATE:** 
Thanks to [danack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/778719/) for pointing out the correct way of doing this withour resorting to using exec() as I did in my original fix:

$image->transformImageColorspace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_SRGB);

I should also note that [contrary to what this page says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739822/php-imagemagick-setcolorspace-not-working) the setImageColorspace() method *does* work as intended, as its function is not to actually make changes to the file colorspace, but only to set the colorspace that the image *claims* to be in (aka "[sets the colorspace member of the Image structure](http://www.imagemagick.org/api/colorspace.php)" according to the ImageMagick API documentation). transformImageColorSpace() in contrast actually makes the required changes to make an image display as that colorspace.

Comment: The correct function to use is Imagick::transformImageColorspace - a demo of it in action http://www.phpimagick.com/Imagick/transformImageColorspace to allow you to analzye an image per channel.

Comment: This (both your comment and the website you link to) is incredibly useful thanks - I notice Imagick::transformImageColorspace is completely missing from php.net documentation. I know it is in the imagemagick API documentation, but I'd have been hard pressed to distinguish the difference between 'transform' and 'set' from that.